# Groovy, Grails Problems with chaining closures

Tags: grails, groovy

I am stumped and a little help would be appreciated..

1) this works

```
def critQuery = Vlan.createCriteria()
def criteria = criteriaUtil.aproxFilterClosure.curry(Vlan, params)
vlanList = critQuery(criteria)
```

2) this works too

```
def critQuery = Vlan.createCriteria()
def criteria = {eq('dot1qId', 121.toLong())}
def ordering = {order('name','asc')}
def query = criteria << ordering
vlanList = critQuery(query)
```

3) but this does not work

```
def critQuery = Vlan.createCriteria()
def criteria = criteriaUtil.aproxFilterClosure.curry(Vlan, params)
def ordering = {order('name','asc')}
def query = criteria << ordering
vlanList = critQuery(query)
```

ErrorMsg: No signature of method: ch.ethz.id.netcenter.common.util.CriteriaUtil$_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class..

```
class CriteriaUtil {
    ..
    def aproxFilterClosure = {myClass, map ->
           ...
    }
    ..
}
```

What would be the correct way to chain thes two closures criteria and ordering?

Comment: Can you achieve what you're after using [named queries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html)?

Comment: you appear to be missing some of the error message in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ["Closures always return a value"](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures+-+Formal+Definition).  Your `criteria` closure is getting fed the upstream result from the `ordering` query, which it is not defined to accept (Groovy is trying to feed it the curried values + the result from `ordering`, for a total of 3 params).

Two potential ways of hacking around this:

1. You could get around this by adding another throwaway param to the aproxFilterClosure that you ignore.
2. Or you could try wrapping it in something like this:

   ```
   def x = {Object [] s-> criteria(Arrays.asList(s).subList(0, criteria.maximumNumberOfParameters))}
   ```

   This will accept an arbitrary number of params, then call your criteria closure with only the params it can handle.

I'm not saying I'm in love with either of these ideas, but they may get you over the specific error you're seeing, if this path is your way forward.

Comment: I tried your first recommandation and it works. You are my hero!